# matplotlib does not support generators as input

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, generator, ensemble-learning

I am running the Python 2 notebook at this site https://github.com/vsmolyakov/experiments_with_python/blob/master/chp01/ensemble_methods.ipynb  to practice ensemble methods with python, and getting an error when running this part of the code in Python 3:

```
plt.figure()
(_, caps, _) = plt.errorbar(num_est, bg_clf_cv_mean, yerr=bg_clf_cv_std, c='blue', fmt='-o', capsize=5)
for cap in caps:
    cap.set_markeredgewidth(1)                                                                                                                                
plt.ylabel('Accuracy'); plt.xlabel('Ensemble Size'); plt.title('Bagging Tree Ensemble');
plt.show()
```

The error is "matplotlib does not support generators as input"
What is the solution?

Comment: what is the line that is causing the error ? and what kind of input are you feeding matplotlib ?

Comment: That notebook is clearly Python 2.x code from 2017 (you can tell from the no parentheses in a `print` statement). So, if you can't find a later version, you have to update it from 2-to-3. I suggest you contact the author to contribute your 3.x updates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In that example
there is a line `num_est = map(int, np.linspace(1,100,20))`. This produces a list in python 2.7. But in python 3 it is just a generator. The map is strange anyways, so I'd recommend to replace that line by

```
num_est = np.linspace(1,100,20).astype(int)
```

Comment: is it ok to typecast into list(map). How do I find which one is more efficient?

Comment: @AAI `.astype(int)` is **way faster**, although if you only have some 20 elements both would still be in the microsecond regime or below.